# can't display alert after ajax post in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net mvc application, I want to display an alert after the client register himself, my application is working correctly, this is the only thing that's left to do, I'm certain im missing something stupid

```
    public ActionResult Register(Client client)
    {
           ClientDAL objClientDAL = new ClientDAL();

           objClientDAL.Insert(client);

           return Json(new { msg = "Thank you!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and in my view

```
                $("#btnSalvar").click(function () {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",                              
                            url: "/Home/Register",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                              
                            data:
                                {
                                    ID: $('#txtMatricula').val(),
                                    Name: $('#txtNome').val(),
                                    Age: $('#txtIdade').val(),
                                    StateID: $('#ddlEstados').val(),
                                    CityID: $('#ddlCidades').val(),
                                    Gender: $('#Fumante').val()
                                },

                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                alert(data.msg);                                       
                            },

                            error: function (data)
                            {
                                alert(data.msg); 
                            },

                        });
                });
```

as I said everything is working just fine, but I can't display the message in alert form, when I try this out, it appears like this...

{"msg":"Thank you!"} in a blank page, like it's just ignoring my success function, I'm new to asp.net mvc.

(by the way you guys might noticed that some words are different like the url, or the button, it's because english is not my native language, so I just translated the crucial parts so you guys can understand better whats happening).

Comment: call `e.preventDefault()` inside click event so it will not do normal navigation

Comment: Also why are you defining the click event handler inside another function definition ? It does not make sense!

Comment: lol, that's true , i'm new to this so there's a lot of things that i'm doing wrong still

Comment: Also your action method name is `Register` , but your client side code is calling some other action method. Post the correct code!

Comment: as i said, it is correct , it's just translated, the actual code is in portuguese, and you guys won't understand anything so i just translated what was necessary, but the method and the register part is working mate

Comment: the e.preventDefault worked partially, it's going to a blank page and my alert is appearing but with no message in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i try this out, it appears like this... {"msg":"Thank you!"} in a
>   blank page

That means your client side code to make the Ajax code is not being executed.

This usually happens when you have a button inside a `form` tag and your wire up some ajax code to handle the button click/form submit to be ajaxified, but forgot to stop/prevent the normal form submit behavior.

You can use the  [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)  method to do so.

**I also see few other issues with your code**

Your `click` event handler is written inside another function. That does not make any sense. Who is calling that method  ? If nobody is calling that method, then your `click` event handler will not be registered. It is best to wire up the click event handler in [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event.

Also I see you are specifying the `contentType` option in the ajax call. This will send the `Content-Type` header value as `application/json` and the model binder tries to read the data from the request body. But you are sending a JavaScript object as the `data` property. Either remove the `contentType` from your code or use `JSON.stringify` method to create a JSON string version of your object and send that as the `data` property of the `$.ajax` option. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378657/mvc-multiple-parameter-ajax-call/53378805#53378805) post for sample code. This is helpful when sending a complex object.

This should work

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnSalvar").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Register",
                data:
                    {
                        Id: 3,
                        Title: "Scott",
                        Age:2,
                    },

                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                    console.log(status)
                },

            });
    });

})
```

Comment: that worked!! thank you for your time sir, i already fixed the other mistakes you pointed.